# Let a button perform a different action on every 6th click

Tags: javascript

Unfortunately I don´t really know what I am doing... I created a button that refreshes just one part of my website with a randomly chosen HTML snippet. Now I want this button to choose a specific snippet every 6th time I click it. If I keep clicking, it will again choose random snippets till it has been clicked 6 times again ...

```
function loadExternalHTMLPage() {
  var xmlhttp;
  var pagesToDisplay = [
    'advice001.html',
    'advice002.html',
    'advice003.html',
    'advice004.html',
    'advice005.html',
    'advice009.html',
    'advice012.html',
    'advice013.html',
    'advice014.html',
    'advice015.html',
  ];
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("contentArea").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * pagesToDisplay.length);
  xmlhttp.open("GET", pagesToDisplay[randomnumber], true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: I don't see a button click handler in your code, nor any attempt to implement your requirement. Also, coding becomes a lot easier when you properly indent your code.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP requests you make seem irrelevant to your problem statement, so I will just focus on making the difference on each 6<sup>th</sup> click:

You can use global counter variable and use the remainder operator (`%`) to detect whether that count is a multiple of 6 or not:

```js
var clickCount = 0;

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    clickCount++;
    if (clickCount % 6) {
        console.log("not the 6th time");
    } else {
        console.log("the 6th time");
    }
});
```

```html
<button>click me</button>
```

The `if ... else` construct is what you need to extend to execute whatever you want to do in either case.

Answer (score 0):

```
 This should work. Store a variable outside function. Increment it on random number selection. When number of times is equal to 6, equate the number to 0.

   var number_times = 0;
    function loadExternalHTMLPage() {
      var xmlhttp;
      var pagesToDisplay = [
      'advice001.html',
      'advice002.html',
      'advice003.html',
      'advice004.html',
      'advice005.html',
      'advice009.html',
      'advice012.html',
      'advice013.html',
      'advice014.html',
      'advice015.html',];
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("contentArea").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      var randomnumber;
      if( number_times > 5 ){
        randomnumber = 6;
        number_times = 0
      } else {
        randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * pagesToDisplay.length);
        number_times++;
      }


      xmlhttp.open("GET", pagesToDisplay[randomnumber], true);
      xmlhttp.send();

    }
```